# Ngrx: How to select two or more properties changes using single selector

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have reactive Form Angular application using NGRX store. Rather than subscribe to entire state want to subscribe some of fields changes e.g. name,city.

I am trying to selectFormNameCity selector but always its subscribing for single properties.

Tried both OR and AND operator condition in selector but not working as expected.

How to achieve using single selector `selectFormNameCity` for  `name` and  `city` if one of the value changed should get subscribe in component.

Here is the code stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7975sh?file=src/app/test.selector.ts).

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export const selectForm = createFeatureSelector<any>('form');
export const name = createSelector(selectForm, (state) => state.info.name);
export const city = createSelector(selectForm, (state) => state.info.city);

export const selectFormNameCity = createSelector(name, city, (name, city) => {
  return { name, city };
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t get your use case, but it will work if you change the selector a bit:

```
export const selectFormNameCity = createSelector(name, city, (name, city) => {
  return {name, city};
});
```

And it will give you the next output:

```
{name: "vvvv", city: ""}
{name: "vvvv", city: "123213"}
{name: "44vvvv", city: "123213"}
```